# Why not see if a climb right column above

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://s1.busteco.ro/arthur_prtab_git/margareta#)

I want to climb right above my column and why I put this code (for monent is not server)

```
.practitioner .right{
    width: 26%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -18em; //this is modification
}
```

everything is ok but my column is put back and can not see.

Try to put this code on the site and see what happens ...
I tried to add a higher z-index but does not go

Can you tell me please what is the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z-index` is only computed if the element is absolute positioned:

```
div.main.practitioner {
    position: relative;
}

div.main.practitioner .right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;

    width: 26%;
    margin-top: -18em; //this is modification
}
```

When a element's position is `absolute` it becomes "relative" to the closiest relative positioned ancestor. That's why `div.main.practitioner` is set to be relative positioned.